# How to get list of files in a branch of of a GitHub repo

Tags: github

**The problem statement:** In my project,  GIT HUB is being used as a version controlling software. Here we need to check whether all artifacts are being checked in by all developers. So the plan is to consume if any service available in Git Hub to get access of all the current checked in artifacts from that branch. Once we have that list ready then it will be matched with entire list of artifacts( already have a list) those were developed. It will help us to prepare the delta/sub set of artifacts those are not checked in.

Any help/suggestion/better approach is highly appreciated.

Cheers!!
Nilanjan

Comment: Are you essentially looking for a list of files in a branch?  Are you looking to test that the code works in a particular branch?

Comment: If a branch is cut from an existing branch, then it already has evrything from the source branch. That is until the source branch changes. You can always check this by doing a `git diff <branch a>..<branch b>` to see changes. If you want to see the changes at a commit level use `git log <a>..<b>`. Git however does not know abt files. It only knows commits. I am not sure if there is a way in git to see changes on a file level. There is something called `dirstat`  but I have never used it so cant comment on it. Look it up and see if it helps

Comment: Thanks leoOrion for your reply. I will try that. bk2204 thanks for your response. Essentially, the requirement is to get the list of files from a directory created under Master branch. Example -> I have a folder "Script" created in Master Branch. In that folder I have two files A.js and B.js. I need to get  the file names in side that Folder. So the result will be A.js and B.js. If we have other folders and that is quite obvious then same is applicable to those as well.